# Azure .NET app with JRE(java) support

Tags: java, azure-web-app-service

we have a basic ASP.NET mvc app which uses third party tool embedded in to it. This tool requires JRE(java run time)  for executing.

Is there any way we could deploy this mvc app to Azure?

Comment: Assume that there *is* a way, try it, and if you get stuck ask about that.

Comment: I have been playing around with Azure web app , it allows only one platform to be used for the app service at any given point.

I know other NON Azure options exist but wondering how it can be done with Azure? is it even possible?

Comment: @user6163763 What is the third party tool required JRE? If the third party tool requires JRE via the code like `ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", Command);`, I think you can try to [add the related path of Java into the current environment variable](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables) or directly use the absolute Java path on Azure like `D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe` to change the source code.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - the tool is primarily written in Java but uses IKVM to make it consumable in .NET applications.

Comment: @user6163763 Did you make the app works with IKVM on your local machine?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - Yes, it works locally with out adding any special references

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set by default on azure webapp machines.. So this should work if it depends on JRE.. Please try it out and if it does not work, please msg me the azure webapp name and I can investigate.